# Tomcat application: Rewrite rule for IIS7

Tags: tomcat, iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, redirect

I have been able to rewrite urls to my tomcat applications running on port 8080 and 8090 to something like this format "`http://localhost/app1`" using IIS7 reverse proxy and rewrite rules,
Sample code I used is as follows...

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(alfresco.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(http?)://" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}://localhost:8090/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Now the format I want it to use is something like this: `app1.myhost.com, app2.myhost.com`

Where `myhost.com` could refer to my local hostname, I have already defined it in my hosts file in Windows directory.
I have tried many methods but they all append `www.` before the url.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Do you have a clear example of what you want to do?

Comment: let me put it this way i want app1.myhost.com to redirect to a tomcat application whose url is like this localhost:8080/app1, without changing the url which is app1.myhost.com

Comment: closing this thread, solved it :)